# What's wrong with my particle program?

Tags: shader, opengl-es-2.0, particle-system

I use a texture picture to create a particle effect program using OpenGLES 2.0 on iOS. The shaders of the program is blow, I have used

> glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

to make it transparent, but it looks like still wrong.

texture image
[image: texture image]

particle effect
[image: particle effect]

```
    const char* vertShaderCode="uniform mat4 trans;\n"
    "uniform mat4 proj;\n"
    "attribute vec3 coord;\n"
    "attribute vec2 texcoord;\n"
    "attribute vec4 color;\n"
    "varying vec2 outUV;\n"
    "varying vec4 m_Color;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_Position = proj*trans*vec4(coord,1.0);\n"
    "    outUV = texcoord;\n"
    "    m_Color = color;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    ;

    const char* fragShaderCode="#ifdef GL_ES\n"
    "precision highp float;\n"
    "#endif\n"
    "uniform sampler2D m_texture;\n"
    "varying vec2 outUV\n;"
    "varying vec4 m_Color;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec4 texColor = texture2D(m_texture,outUV);\n"
    "    gl_FragColor = vec4((texColor.xyz + m_Color.xyz)*0.5, texColor.w);\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    ;
```

Comment: When you use that sort of blending you usually need to render your particles from back to front (i.e. furthest from the camera first). Additive blending glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE) with depth test off doesn't suffer from that requirement.